# What's the difference between 穿 and 穿出？

Tags: meaning, difference

I think I understand the difference, but I know that 穿 is passes through something (one of the meanings), but 穿出 is also..I saw the sentence: 看到喜欢的都想把它穿出来 (this is a phrase from a video where a girl made clothes similar to drawings of an object, for example vases). And I don't understand why can't just say 穿？

Answer (score 1):

穿出 is not a word. The sentence should be split into 穿/出来.
出来 is more specific that you are going out with that clothing, while 穿 is more generic that you could wear it at any time.

Answer (score 1):

> 看到喜欢的都想把它穿出来

The full context of the sentence would be: "(當我)看到(我)喜欢的(衣服我)都想把它**穿出来**(讓大家看看/欣賞).". Here, "穿出来" is an abbreviate phrase of:

- (把我喜欢的衣服都)**穿出来** = (把我喜欢的衣服都)**穿上身**(從更衣室)**走出來**.

Note that "(把我喜欢的衣服都)穿来(穿上身, wear on)讓大家看看/欣賞" is also acceptable, as it is understood that one must come out of the dressing room to permit viewing of others, so "出" can be eliminated. However, the term can not be reduced to the verb "穿" without being followed by a modifier (出来, 来).